# Custom Sorting an array in java using Two values , x and y

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparator

I am trying to sort the array based on `x` values in case `x` value is same , sort it according to `y`. After sorting print the values I get an **exception**, I am calling compare method by overriding compare method of Comparator Interface.

```
class coder
{
    int x,y,index;
}
public class CoderRating  implements Comparator<coder>{
    public int compare(coder A,coder B)
    {
        if(A.x==B.x)
        {
            if(A.y<B.y)
            return -1;
            else if(A.y>B.y)
            return 1;
            else
            return 0;
        }

        else if(A.x<B.x)
        return -1;

        else
        return 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        coder []c=new coder[n];

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            c[i]=new coder();
            c[i].x=sc.nextInt();
            c[i].y=sc.nextInt();
            c[i].index=i;
        }
        Arrays.sort(c);
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(c[i].x + "  "+c[i].y );
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: What is the exception? a\d where do you get it?

Comment: And please go over [java coding conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html)

Comment: Would you mind changing `coder class` into `Coder class`??? If you do it I would be sooooo happy! ;-) (class names start with uppercase) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the wrong overload of `sort`, it should be:

```
Arrays.sort(c, new CoderRating());
```

Currently, you're calling [this sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-java.lang.Object:A-) method instead of [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-), specifying your comparator hence the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the Arrays.sort on coder object and not passing any comparator object so Arrays.sort is looking for comparable in Coder class.
2 solutions to your problem:

1. change: Pass the comparator which you want while sorting coder array.
   Change **`Arrays.sort(c)`** to  **`Arrays.sort(c,new CoderRating())`**;
2. implement comparable in coder. Override the compareTo method and move the code of compare method inside CoderRating  to the compareTo method in Coder.

**PS: For your code cleanup** :

Change:

```
       `if(A.y<B.y)
            return -1;
        else if(A.y>B.y)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;`
```

can be changed to one liner:

`return Integer.compare(A.y, B.y);`

Output:

`3
1 2
2 3
2 1
1 2
2 1
2 3`

Comment: `Integer.compare(A.y, B.y);` surely reduces the code a bit but if you want to go as deep as reducing the code as much as possible then one could even do `Arrays.sort(c, Comparator.comparingInt(coder::getX).thenComparingInt(coder::getY));` therefore rendering the `CoderRating` class obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the sorting algorithm with the `Comparator` you have implemented:

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
int n=sc.nextInt();
coder []c=new coder[10];

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    c[i]=new coder();
    c[i].x=sc.nextInt();
    c[i].y=sc.nextInt();
    c[i].index=i;
}
Arrays.sort(c, new CoderRating()); //this is how it should be called
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    System.out.println(c[i].x + "  "+c[i].y );
}
```

**output:**

[image]